# Celery is repeating my tasks three times

Tags: django, redis, celery

I call some tasks in celery one time but celery executes all of them three times. 
Is it an expected behavior of celery or is it a misconfiguration?

I'm using Django 1.5.11, Celery 3.1.23 and Redis 3.0.6.

Comment: Hey Paulo, were you able to resolve the issue eventually?

Are your tasks scheduled to execute in the future using the 'eta' option? It seems that there is some problem with using the 'eta' option with Redis as Celery broker: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4400

Answer (score 0):

You may have some stray workers executing the tasks or an celery flower instance may try to "help" recover unacked messages.

Make sure that only one instance of celery is running with `ps -Af | grep celerybeat` and check if you have any flower instance running by accessing `http://localhost:5555` (it usually runs on that port).

Comment: Thanks, Dana. Unfortunately I got only one instance of celery and I don't have flower running.